# Install Remote Desktop (Ubuntu-desktop, xRDP or whatever) on Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: 18.04, 16.10, 18.10, vps

How can we setup a Desktop GUI on our remote VPS server, where we have only access to it's terminal (and no DESKTOP is setup there yet), so after that we could connect to that desktop (using Windows 10 Remote Desktop, VNC or whatever...). What is **step-by-step**? i.e.

```
apt-get install ...
// then ???
```

then how to configure, setup login password & user, etc... what is step-by-step?

**Note!** I can't follow the tutorials where is said "click this or that" because I have only access to terminal and can only do things in command-line. So, I need to know how to setup everything completely from terminal.

Comment: @OrganicMarble , thnx. I've updated question and removing this comment too shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. My 3 favorite protocols are:

- TeamViewer
- NX
- VNC

In my experience NX is really good but hard to configure. VNC is more for incidental usage and you have to be careful to keep it secure. TeamViewer is the most mature and easiest to use and setup.

To start using TeamViewer you have to use the console in the administration panel of your VPS provider. That's the equivalent of plugging a monitor and keyboard directly to your virtual server. And not like using SSH over the internet.

That's where you install the Ubuntu Desktop and login for the first time. Then follow this howto: [TeamViewer on Linux](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-install-TeamViewer-on-Ubuntu/ta-p/45)

Comment: No, probably I didnt correctly asked. I don't have a GUI, so i can't follow that tutorial (where is said "click this or that" ). I cant click anything, I have only access to Command-Line terminal to my VPS